# PDO で binValue を使ってもバインドされない．

Tags: php, pdo

PDO で binValue を使ってもバインドされないバグが起きています．

binValue の後に errorinfo を挟んだ結果 "HY093" とでました．debugDumpParams もしたのですが，バインドされていない文字列が結果として帰って来ました.

bindValue している変数は実数なので，調べた結果 PARAM_STR にしたのですが，PARAM_INT で試してもダメでした．

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn['host'], $dsn['user'], $dsn['pass'], $dsn['driver_options']);
try {
  $pdo->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
  $sql =  "SELECT * FROM location WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText('LineString(? ?, ? ?)'), latlng)";
  $select_loc = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $select_loc->bindValue(1, $ne_lng, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $select_loc->bindValue(2, $ne_lat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $select_loc->bindValue(3, $sw_lng, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $select_loc->bindValue(4, $sw_lat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $select_loc->execute();

  $loc = $select_loc->fetch();

} catch(PDOException $e) {
  $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: `$select_loc->bindValue(1, strval($ne_lng), PDO::PARAM_STR);` としてみて下さい(他も同様)。

Comment: やってみましたがバインドされませんでした．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'LineString(? ?, ? ?)'`がただの文字列と扱われているのだと思います。

```
CONCAT('LineString(', ?, ' ', ?, ', ', ?, ' ', ?, ')')
```

のように結合するか、あるいはPHP側でパラメーターを埋め込めばいいのではないでしょうか。